# enable submit button when FromDate and ToDate are Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to enable submit button when FromDate and ToDate are Selected.

In my Case all Form is fill-up for enable submit button.

```js
 $('#myform > input').on('input', function() {
   var empty = false;
   $('form > input, form > select').each(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == '') {
       empty = true;
     }
   });

   if (empty) {
     $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
     $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  Name
  <input type="text" id="" name="name" />
  <br/>
  <br/>From Date
  <input type="date" name="fdate" />
  <br/>
  <br/>To Date
  <input type="date" name="fdate" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

My Requirement is when FromDate and ToDate are Selected than  submit button should be enable.

Comment: You want to check all inputs or only date inputs?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#myform > input').on('input', function () {
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input[type=date], form > select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

```html
<form id="myform">
Name
<input type="text" id="" name="name" /><br/><br/>

From Date
<input type="date"  name="fdate1" /><br/><br/>
To Date
<input type="date"  name="fdate2" /><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>></script>
```

This works fine ;), your code was good, but `$("form > input")` will check every input date AND name ;)

Comment: These solution do not work if end user change the date inputs to empty after been filled.. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make submit button `disabled` every time the user input or change the date fields:

```js
var $formInputsDate = $('#myform > input[type="date"]'),
    $submit = $('#register');

$formInputsDate.on('input change', function () {
  var isEmpty = false;
  $formInputsDate.each(function () {
    $(this).val() === '' && (isEmpty = true);
  });
  return isEmpty ? $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled') : $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  Name
  <input type="text" id="" name="name"><br><br>

  From Date
  <input type="date"  name="fdate1"><br><br>

  To Date
  <input type="date"  name="fdate2"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Note that you can attach the event handler function to all inputs in the form by using `$('#myform > input')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try bind submit event:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function () {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > input, form > select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

and remove disabled attribute:

```
<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register"/>
```

Comment: The submit button is disabled by default, I don't believe this will enable the button when the inputs are filled in. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @SteevePitis it was also not needed to down-vote his answer for this.

Comment: @Franco add info to remove disabled attribute.

Comment: @jcubic yes I already saw it. What I  really don't understand is why people is so easily down-voting answers without a good reason.

Comment: I've remove my down vote, but he want to enable/disable the submit button, you just can't check this on submit ...